# Orientdb - Traverse all possible N degree separation paths between vertexes

Tags: orientdb2.2

Is it possible to find out all possible paths with  N degree of separation between two nodes in Orientdb?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT $path FROM  ( TRAVERSE out() FROM (select from entities where id ='A') WHILE $depth <= N ) where id ='B'
```